# Many-to-Many Relationships - Movie - Role - Actor

Tags: django

I'm not sure what is the best solution to describe this conceptual model. I know how to create a many to many relationship, but not with role inside this relation. Could you please let me know what is the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). We can thus create three models, and define a `ManyToManyField` where the `Role` is the `through` model:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    synopsis = models.TextField()
    duration = models.DurationField()

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, through='Role', related_name='actors')

class Role(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a try.

Comment: Regarding the template, how can I iterate to display a role for a specific movie? I managed to do it for another case with a foreign key.

Comment: @Yann: you just iterate with `mymovie.role_set.all()`.

Comment: I worked but I can't display only `order < 5` from class Role,                                         `Role.objects.filter(order__range=[0, 5]),  `movie = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
 role = Role.objects.filter(order__range=[0, 5])
 return render(request, 'bms/visitor/film.html', {'movies': movie}, {'roles': role})`

Comment: @Yann: what do you mean with "can't display one"? You can iterate over the roles, and access `.person` to obtain the related person.

Comment: @Yann: you can filter with `momovie.role_set.filter(order__range=(0,5))`. Note that you can not make calls with parameters in the Django *templates* (this is deliberately restricted), so you will need to do that in the view.

Comment: Sorry I meant, it worked, but I want to display only record where order is < 5 class `Role(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)`

Comment: this is my view : `def movie_detail(request, id):
 movie = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
 role = Role.objects.filter(order__range=[0, 5])
 return render(request, 'bms/visitor/film.html', {'movies': movie}, {'roles': role})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204981/discussion-between-yann-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: I tried this `role = Role_set.filter(order__range=[0, 5])` I had

name 'Role_set' is not defined