# Laravel many to many: Movie - Person - Role

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Would like to have models & relationships where I have:

- movies
- persons
- roles (director, script, actor, etc.)

If it is just movies & persons I could set up a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) (create `person_role` migration and add `$this->belongsToMany()` to both Person and Role models)
However: person X can be an **actor** in movie A and be both **actor** and **director** in movie B.
I saw the [Django answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493407/many-to-many-relationships-movie-role-actor), but not sure how this is done in Laravel. (update: the Django answer refers to "role" being the name of the character. In my case: role = actor/director/writer/...)

**Update**: more details of the environment and my attempts.

I created movies, persons, roles and the lookup table movie_person_role (aka triple pivot):

```
movies
- id
- name

persons
- id
- name

roles
- id
- name [director, script, actor, etc.]

movie_person_role
- id
- foreignId: movie_id
- foreignId: person_id
- foreignId: role_id
```

method:

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    public function persons() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person', 'movie_person_role', 'movie_id', 'person_id')->withPivot('role_id');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'movie_person_role', 'movie_id', 'role_id')->withPivot('person_id');
    }
}
```

seeder:

```
        $id = DB::table('movies')->insertGetId([
            'name' => 'Redbad',
        ]);
        $m = App\Movies::find($id);
        $w->persons()->attach([
            App\Person::name('Roel Reiné')->first()->id => ['role_id' => App\Role::name('director')->first()->id],
            App\Person::name('Alex van Galen')->first()->id => ['role_id' => App\Role::name('writer')->first()->id],
            App\Person::name('Jonathan Banks')->first()->id => ['role_id' => App\Role::name('actor')->first()->id],
        ])
```

(could be there are cleaner ways of defining the seeds)

This correctly links e.g. `person` "Roel Reiné" as `role` "director" to `movie` "Redbad".

What remains: how to get list of persons + roles for a movie?

Status at the moment is that I can get the persons (without their role):

tinker:

```
>>> App\Movie::where('title','Redbad')->with('persons')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3204
     all: [
       App\Work {#3224
         id: 1,
         name: "Redbad",
         persons: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3179
           all: [
             App\Person {#3250
               id: 2,
               name: "Roel Reiné",
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3249
                 movie_id: 1,
                 person_id: 2,
                 role_id: 1,
               },
             },
    ...
```

This gives the Persons involved in the Redbad movie. And in the pivot object I see the role id.
It allows me to do queries like `$movie->persons()->where('role_id',4)->get()` which gives me all the `actors` for a specific movie or `

But I would prefer eager loading of the role, just like the person, so that I can easily create a list of movies, with the persons and their role. E.g.

```
movie A - person K - role director
movie A - person L - role director
movie A - person L - role actor
movie B - person M - role director
movie B - person N - role actor
```

Comment: I think what you need is the ``hasManyThrough`` relationship. [Laradoc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that would be applicable if I had `movie-person-hobbies` and wanted to get the hobbies of the people involved in a movie. What I want to get is: the persons and their role for a movie.

Answer (score 1):

The tables required to define this relationship:

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string
    ...

roles
    id - integer
    name - string
    user_id - integer
    movie_id - integer

movies
    id - integer
    title - string
```

Implementation

let's define the movies method on our User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Movie', 'roles', 'user_id', 'movie_id')->withPivot('name');
    }
}
```

Defining The Inverse Of The Relationship

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Movie extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'roles', 'movie_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('name');
    }
}
```

Once the relationship is defined, you may access the user's movies using the movies dynamic property:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->movies as $movie) {
    // You may access the intermediate table using the pivot attribute on the models:
    echo $movie->pivot->name; // retrieve the role name for user #1 in $movie
}
```

Comment: In my case `role` is "actor", "director", etc. I get the feeling in your answer you assumed it was the name of the character. Your response did help me to make progress though, but I am not there yet. I have added updated the original post to provide more details.

Comment: Specifically, your answer has a table that stores a character name and link it with a movie and a person. My need is to link 3 tables: 1) movie, 2) person and 3) role (director/writer/actor/etc) and to have an "eloquent" way of retrieving e.g. person+role for a movie.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [Eager Load Pivot Relations](https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations/) package.

Author has an [example project](https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations-examples).